# Ext.Ajax.request does not work inside Ext.onReady?

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to use Ext.Ajax.request in ExtJS 4.02a but it will not run at all inside of Ext.onReady, when I take it outside of Ext.onReady it runs fine. Is there some config I am missing?

My call is set-up as follows:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '../json?queryName=tapAccounts&parameters=',
    success: function(response) {
        accounts = Ext.decode(response.responseText)
    }
});
```

Comment: I had something messed up in my `Ext.require` clause so `Ext.onReady` was not firing at all... strange that it didn't throw an error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my i know how do you put your ajax inside `onready`???

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
     //put ajax here
});
```

take look at my sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/U2Gz2)

Comment: As above my problem was with my `Ext.require` clause. Of course this is the correct answer to my question, this would be how you would put ajax inside of Ext.onReady. It's inside of it and everything...